# load NxNxN fortran binary matrix into matlab and retaining same ijk ordering

Tags: arrays, matlab, fortran, reshape

If I write out a fortran NxNxN array in binary then read it back into matlab and use

```
array = RESHAPE(inputdata,[N N N])
```

will it retain the same structure? i.e. will array(i,j,k) in Matlab correspond to array(i,j,k) in Fortran? Or do I have to change the ordering? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? You already wrote that one line code and you ask if it will retain the same structure, well, have you tried to check that and see for yourself?

Comment: Well I only have the output from the Fortran code so I can't check it that quickly. I thought it would be a quick yes/no answer from someone with experience which would save me 30 minutes of coding.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_major#Column-major_order

Answer (score 1):

Matlab and Fortran both use column-major storage order, so if you just did something like `write(iounit) array`, the example you posted should be fine as is.

Comment: Yes, but best with stream access (sequential would probably work, but there may be issues with record length limits).